# TailwindCSS default colours is not being recognised in my project

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css, styling

I have added custom colors to my TailwindCSS project, however, when I try and use a built-in color such as `text-blue-200` it is not recognized within the HTML file.

Any idea what this could be?

Here is my tailwindconfig file

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ['./public/**/*.{html, js}'],
  theme: {
    colors: {
      transparent: 'transparent',
      current: 'currentColor',
      'golden': '#cdaa60',
      'light-brown': '#6b5635',
      'dark-brown': '#433627',
      'light-green': '#848468',
      'dark': '#141115',
      'light': '#fff',
      'black': '#000',
      'error': '#ff6961'
    },
    fontFamily: {
      redressed: ['Prata', 'serif']
    }
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme#overriding-the-default-theme), when you add configuration directly in the `theme` property "will completely replace Tailwind’s default configuration for that key." Thus, by providing color configuration in `theme.colors`, your provided colors will completely replace the Tailwind default color values. Since you don't have `blue-200` or `blue.200` in your colors, this no longer exists and no CSS rule for `text-blue-200` is built by Tailwind.

If you would like to retain the Tailwind default colors, you should consider defining your extra colors in `theme.extend.colors`, as per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme#extending-the-default-theme):

> If you’d like to preserve the default values for a theme option but also add new values, add your extensions under the `theme.extend` key in your configuration file. Values under this key are merged with existing `theme` values and automatically become available as new classes that you can use.

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ['./public/**/*.{html, js}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        // Tailwind's default color palette has these colors, so it is
        // obsolete to define them again here.
        // transparent: 'transparent',
        // current: 'currentColor',
        'golden': '#cdaa60',
        'light-brown': '#6b5635',
        'dark-brown': '#433627',
        'light-green': '#848468',
        'dark': '#141115',
        'light': '#fff',
        // Tailwind's default color palette has this color, so it is
        // obsolete to define it again here.
        // 'black': '#000',
        'error': '#ff6961'
      },
    },
    fontFamily: {
      redressed: ['Prata', 'serif']
    }
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```